# Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following Firestore listener:

```
firestore
        .collection('conversations')
        .where('id', '==', 'someId')
        .onSnapshot(callback)
```

With the following rules set up for the collection:

```
match /conversations/{document} {
        allow read: if (request.auth.uid in resource.data.userIds) == true;
        allow write: if (request.auth.uid in resource.data.userIds) == true
```

When I plug in this listener in useEffect() I get the error:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.15.0): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.

How come since I am for sure logged in and also the userId of the user logged in is in the userIds array of conversation?

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your security rules are set to allow document reads in the `conversations` collection where the UID of the authenticated user exists in `userIds` array, while your query tries to return documents from the same collection where the value of the `id` field is equal to `someId` value. Since the rules are set to allow an operation other than the one you perform, the Firebase server rejects that operation, hence the failure.

To create a query that should satisfy your rules, you have to use `array-contains` operator:

```
firestore
    .collection('conversations')
    .where('userIds', 'array-contains, uid)
    .onSnapshot(callback)
```

Where the `uid` is the UID of the authenticated user.

Comment: Ah ok yeah, that works, but I also added `.where('id', '==', 'someId')` so i filter just that one document. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear that it worked :)

Comment: Actually one question Alex, still not sure why I need the userIds where query? Because shouldnt this be true? `if (request.auth.uid in resource.data.userIds) == true;` Why do I need the userId where query to filter by documentId?

Comment: You need the userIds *array-contains* query to satisfy the rules. If you need another query, then you have to the change rules too, so it can allow the query you need to perform.

Comment: If you have another query/rules, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.